# Regex grab password from net use

Tags: regex, logging, logstash

SecondEdit: We have command line auditing enabled and the logs going to elasticsearch.  Basically, I'll be doing this subst in logstash, or trying to. It's actually been almost nil but I'm trying to cover all the bases.

We are monitoring cmd line activity on hosts and while it's policy that you aren't supposed to enter your password in clear text on the cmd line, people will.

So I'm looking for a way to detect when someone enters their password and then subst out the password for hashes. The 1.1.1.8 is an example, it could be any ip address.

From this I want to detect if there is a password there

net  use  I: \1.1.1.8\E$ /user:domain\username **password** /persistent:yes

Look behind, almost seems to have it but I can't get it to stop after the space after username...

(?<=/user:)(.*)(?<=\s)

net  use  I: \1.1.1.8\E$ /user:**domain\username password** /persistent:yes

when I need it to get -

net  use  I: \1.1.1.8\E$ /user:domain\username **password** /persistent:yes

https://regexr.com/3i6va

... it would be something like this to gsub the password out and replace with ###

```
filter {
if  [event_id] == 4688 {
    mutate {
        gsub => ["[event_data][CommandLine]", "(?<=\/user:)(.*)(?<=\s)", 
"########" ]
}
}
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? You want to install a keylogger (!) and replace as someone types? Or do you just replace the password in the history file? which OS should this run on? This question is unclear at best and also most probably very bad practice at worst

Comment: ... actually, it's pretty clear... no need for some flavor specific quirks to solve that, so the running platform is not a problem. they want to grab the password in there. though I'll admit it's a bit heavy handed for the users, there doesn't seem to be any major harm in it